# Hiding a UITableView section along with all the rows in it

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have 2 sections on my UITableview controller. One of my section has a switch and my requirement is when I set the switch to ON, the second section should be set to hidden along with all its rows. I am calling the following method/code to hide the section when the status of the switch is changed:

```
- (void)setState
{
    myTableViewCell *myCell = [[myTableViewCell alloc] init];
    if ([myCell.mySwitch isOn])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1];
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception for this code which I understand is perfectly true.

```
Name = NSInternalInconsistencyException;
Reason = "Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.";
```

But how can I hide the complete section along with all its rows. If I try to get the index path using `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];` this would just hide the 1st row in the section.

Comment: Is your table view static or dynamic?

Comment: Its is a dynamic table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna hide a whole section when switch is on, just `reloadData` when you click the switch, and return 0 in `numberOfRowsInSection` for that section and return `totalNumberOfSections - howManySwitchesIsOn` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
{  
    if(howManySwitchesIsOn) {
        return totalNumberOfSections - howManySwitchesIsOn; 
    } 
    return totalNumberOfSections;
}  

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   
{  
    if(section should be hide) {
         return 0;
    }
    return howManyRowsForThatSection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Section deletion and insertion in a grouped `UITableView` are accomplished via:

```
- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
- (void)insertSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Check out [SectionHidingDemo](https://github.com/shrtlist/SectionHidingDemo.git), a demo app that illustrates section deletion and insertion in a grouped `UITableView` using those methods.